# Android M Adoptable Storage

Tags: android

I have read about Android M adoptable storage from [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#adoptable-storage)

My Question is if I move a App(Android app) from internal storage of phone to adoptable storage ( using OTG cable + pen drive), what "all files" will be moved from internal storage to adoptable storage.
for example

1) Will it move the app private area to this adoptable storage ?

2) Will .lib and .so files will also move to adoptable storage ?

3) What happen to resource file that has been bundle with apk ?

4) will jars that had been bundle with apk also moved to adoptable storage once app is moved from internal storage to this?

Let add one more point here : as soon as you put sdcard in Android-M devices, it ask for whether to use it as internal storage or as external storage. now tell what happen if move the app to sdcard in both scenario

Please help me out in figuring what actually happens when app moved to adoptable storage. Any edits are most welcome.Thanks

Comment: I would expect all those things to be moved.

Comment: @Buddy  how can I analyse all those things ? didn't find any official page also

Comment: That page says it will move the app's private data (#1).  And all your other questions (#2/3/4) cover what's inside the apk itself.

Answer (score 0):

Having had bad experiences with adoptable-storage on both M and N, I feel qualified to answer: the only things that get moved to SD are the files marked as such in the app, by the programmer/packager. Almost no apps use adoptable storage, and Android gives you no choice. You will need a "hack" to get any value out of adoptable storage, IMHO at the moment it makes no sense to "format as internal". HTH